# Cómo compartir código entre widget y activity y gestionar cuando la app es matada de memoria

Tags: android, android-widget

Hola tengo una app Android con su activity y widget. Básicamente el widget y la app hacen lo mismo, se trata de guardar fichajes horarios del trabajo.

Comparten una clase de tipo IntentService con métodos estáticos que son llamados para almacenar el fichaje en base de datos local y en la nube. El problema lo tengo cuando desde la multitarea cerramos la app.

El widget sigue funcionando y recibe el evento de la pulsación, pero cuando llama a los métodos estáticos del servicio se produce un error por, entiendo, haberse descargado de memoria la app.

La solución la tengo duplicando esa clase entera también dentro de la clase del widget, pero es absurdo duplicar el mismo código y cada vez que modifico algo tener que hacerlo en ambos sitios.

¿Cómo se puede gestionar eso?

¿Hay forma con herencia quizá?

¿El widget podría detectar que la app se ha descargado y recargarla en segundo plano?

Gracias.

Edito para añadir código:

El error:

```
07-11 23:18:12.521 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/widget: onReceive
07-11 23:18:12.521 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/widget: onReceive-->botón pulsadoooo
07-11 23:18:12.527 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
07-11 23:18:12.527 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/FirebaseApp: Notified 0 auth state listeners.
07-11 23:18:12.549 23205-23276/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/widget_InOutService: onHandleIntent
07-11 23:18:12.559 23205-23274/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/FA: Connected to remote service
07-11 23:18:12.568 23205-23276/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/widget_InOutService: pulsadoFichaje
07-11 23:18:12.594 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-11 23:18:12.595 23205-23205/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                      Process: com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto, PID: 23205
                                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_DATOS.Exportacion_Servicio: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2862)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:150)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427)
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Context android.content.Context.getApplicationContext()' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:107)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(LocalBroadcastManager.java:102)
                                                                                          at com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_NEGOCIO.BroadcastNotifier.<init>(BroadcastNotifier.java:44)
                                                                                          at com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_DATOS.Exportacion_Servicio.<init>(Exportacion_Servicio.java:54)
                                                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2859)
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:150) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1427) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
07-11 23:18:22.614 23205-23270/com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.firebase.auth not found.
```

El widget:

```
package com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_PRESENTACION.widgets;

public class InOutWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private IntentFilter intentFilter;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(cntx.getPackageName(), R.layout.hell_desk_widget);
        Log.d("widget", "onReceive");

        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, InOutService.class);
        // Al pulsar el botón del widget
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.INOUT_PULSADO)) {
            Log.d("widget", "onReceive-->botón pulsadooo");
            serviceIntent.putExtra("pulsadoFichaje", true);
            serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        }else{//el widget se actualiza sin pulsar el botón, al insertarlo por ejemplo o reiniciar
            Log.d("widget", "onReceive-->botón NO pulsadooo");
            serviceIntent.putExtra("pulsadoFichaje", false);
            serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        }
        context.startService(serviceIntent);

        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        Log.d("widget", "onUpdate");
        // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
        for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
            updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
        }
    }

    static void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
        Log.d("widget", "onUpdateAppWidget");
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.inout_widget);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.inoutImageButton, R.drawable.ic_timer_black_24dp);
        Intent intentInOutButtonPulsado= new Intent(context, InOutWidget.class);
        intentInOutButtonPulsado.setAction(Constants.INOUT_PULSADO);
        intentInOutButtonPulsado.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId);
        PendingIntent piInOutButtonPulsado = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intentInOutButtonPulsado , PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.inoutImageButton, piInOutButtonPulsado);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    }


    /**
     * Clase interna encargada de modificar y actualizar el estado del dispositivo y del widget en
     * pantalla.
     */
    public static class InOutService extends IntentService {
        SharedPreferences preferences;

        public InOutService() {
            super("InOutWidget$InOutService");
        }

        /**
         * Encargado de manejar el intent que se le pase al servicio. En este caso recibirá el
         * intent que se ha lanzado desde los métodos del widget. 
         */
        @Override
        public void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            Log.d("widget_InOutService", "onHandleIntent");
            // El objeto ComponentName será el que nos permita comunicarnos con el propio widget desde el servicio.
            ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, InOutWidget.class);
            // Creamos un manager para abrir la conexión con la vista remota (el propio widget en pantalla.
            AppWidgetManager mngr = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this);

    //Por defecto si no llega nada es que no es fichaje y solo queremos actualizar botón
            Boolean pulsadoFichaje = intent.getBooleanExtra("pulsadoFichaje", false); 


            String sTipoFichaje= MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this).getString(MySharedPreferences.Key.ULTIMOFICHAJE, "1");

            if (pulsadoFichaje) {
                Log.d("widget_InOutService", "pulsadoFichaje");
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int mMonth = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int mDay = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int mHoras = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int mMinutos = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                String sYear = String.valueOf(mYear);
                String sMonth = String.valueOf(mMonth + 1);
                String sDay = String.valueOf(mDay);
                String sHoras = String.valueOf(mHoras);
                String sMinutos = String.valueOf(mMinutos);
                if ((mMonth + 1) < 10) sMonth = "0" + sMonth;
                if (mDay < 10) sDay = "0" + sDay;
                if (mHoras < 10) sHoras = "0" + sHoras;
                if (mMinutos < 10) sMinutos = "0" + sMinutos;
                String sFechaNormalizada = sYear + "/" + sMonth + "/" + sDay;
                String sHoraNormalizada = sHoras + ":" + sMinutos;

                sTipoFichaje= sTipoFichaje.equalsIgnoreCase("0") ? "1" : "0"; //Fichaje actual será lo contrario del último fichaje

                String sUsuario= MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this).getString(MySharedPreferences.Key.CUENTA, null);
                boolean autoExportar= MySharedPreferences.getInstance(this).getBoolean(MySharedPreferences.Key.AUTO_EXPORTAR, false);
                if (sUsuario != null) {


//AQUÍ ESTÁ LA LLAMADA AL SERVICIO QUE LUEGO DA ERROR
                    Exportacion_Servicio.startActionAñadeFichaje(this, sUsuario, sFechaNormalizada, sHoraNormalizada, sTipoFichaje, "", "0", autoExportar );


                }

            }else { Solo actualizar botón del widget
                Log.d("widget_InOutService", " No pulsadoFichaje");
                //El servicio que añade el fichaje llama a este servicio de nuevo 
                //para actualizar el widget y entrará aquí.
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getPackageName(), R.layout.inout_widget);
                if (sTipoFichaje.equalsIgnoreCase("0")) { //Si tipo fichado es entrada, cambiamos a salida icono(1)
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.inoutImageButton, R.drawable.ic_timer_off_black_24dp);
                } else {
                    views.setImageViewResource(R.id.inoutImageButton, R.drawable.ic_timer_black_24dp);
                }
                mngr.updateAppWidget(cn, views);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

La clase servicio compartida entre el widget y la app:

```
package com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_DATOS;


public class Exportacion_Servicio extends IntentService {


    // Omitidas constantes

// EL PROBLEMA PUEDE VENIR POR NO EXISTIR EL CONTEXTO YA. Ese this no será nada si la app se ha eliminado

    private BroadcastNotifier mBroadcaster = new BroadcastNotifier(this);

    public Exportacion_Servicio() {
        super("Exportacion_Servicio");
    }

    /**
     * Inicia este servicio para realizar la tarea de Añadir un solo fichaje. If
     * the service is already performing a task this action will be queued.
     */
    public static void startActionAñadeFichaje(Context context, String sUsuario, String sFechaNormalizada, String sHoraNormalizada, String sTipoFichaje, String sComentario, String sYaExportado, boolean bExportarAhora) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, Exportacion_Servicio.class);
        intent.setAction(ACTION_AÑADE_FICHAJE);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sUsuario, sUsuario);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sFechaNormalizada, sFechaNormalizada);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sHoraNormalizada, sHoraNormalizada);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sTipoFichaje, sTipoFichaje);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sComentarios, sComentario);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_sYaExportado, sYaExportado);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_bExportarAhora, bExportarAhora);
        context.startService(intent);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_EXPORTACION.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sUsuario);
                handleActionExportacion(param1, true); //Exportación manual desde ExportarFragment
            } else if (ACTION_BORRADO_TABLA_FICHAJES_LOCAL.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_tablaFichajesLocal);
                handleActionBorradoTablaLocal(param1, true); //Con broadcast de notificacion

            } else if (ACTION_AÑADE_FICHAJE.equals(action)) {
                final String param1 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sUsuario);
                final String param2 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sFechaNormalizada);
                final String param3 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sHoraNormalizada);
                final String param4 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sTipoFichaje);
                final String param5 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sComentarios);
                final String param6 = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_sYaExportado);
                final boolean param7 = intent.getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_bExportarAhora, false);
                handleActionAñadeFichaje(param1, param2, param3, param4, param5, param6, param7);

            } else if (ACTION_OBTEN_DATOS_ULTIMO_FICHAJE.equals(action)) {
                handleActionObtenDatosUltimoFichaje();
            } else if (ACTION_OBTEN_CADENA_TABLA_FICHAJES.equals(action)) {
                handleActionObtenCadenaTablaFichajes();
            }
        }
    }


    private void handleActionAñadeFichaje(String sUsuario, String sFechaNormalizada, String sHoraNormalizada, String sTipoFichaje, String sComentarios, String sYaExportado, boolean autoExportar) {

//Omito el acceso a base de datos local para guardar los datos


        mBroadcaster.broadcastIntentConResultadoDeAñadeFichaje(resultadoFichaje, sFechaNormalizada, sTipoFichaje);

        actualizarWidgets(this);


    }


    //Llama al servicio del widget para que actualice el icono del widget
    public void actualizarWidgets(Context context){
        Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, InOutWidget.InOutService.class);
        serviceIntent.putExtra("pulsadoFichaje", false);
        serviceIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startService(serviceIntent);
    }


}
```

La clase que gestiona los broadcast donde finalmente da el error, por lo que parece por no existir contexto cuando se elimina la app:

```
package com.proyectosandroid.miProyecto.CAPA_NEGOCIO;

public class BroadcastNotifier {

    private LocalBroadcastManager mBroadcaster;

    /**
     * Creates a BroadcastNotifier containing an instance of LocalBroadcastManager.
     * LocalBroadcastManager is more efficient than BroadcastManager; because it only
     * broadcasts to components within the app, it doesn't have to do parceling and so forth.
     *
     * @param context a Context from which to get the LocalBroadcastManager
     */
    public BroadcastNotifier(Context context) {

        // Gets an instance of the support library local broadcastmanager
        mBroadcaster = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context);
    }
.............
```

Comment: Podrias incluir el log con el error? y el codigo del widget?

Comment: añadido. Gracias

Comment: Al final lo he solucionado eliminando esta linea de declaración del BroadcastNotifier, y declarándola en cada uno de los métodos estáticos que lo utilizan. Problema resuelto. Aunque los procesos sean matados, el widget puede seguir llamando a los métodos de esa clase. Parece que el problema era del contexto que se perdía si estaba declarado ahí.
public class Exportacion_Servicio extends IntentService {
    private BroadcastNotifier mBroadcaster = new BroadcastNotifier(this);